# Is it possible to add stylesheet with an IE conditional comment when enqueing in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm updating my self-built theme, and easily made a number of changes already.

My theme's stylesheet is added to the page head via wp_enqueue_style in the functions.php file, as follows:

```
function gridded_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'themever-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gridded_enqueue_styles');
```

The stylesheet is loaded, the page renders, all good.

Now I need to add some stylesheets with an IE conditional comment like following:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://theme_path/css/ie7.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48581/enqueue-different-stylesheets-using-ie-conditionals

Comment: thanks. i already got the solution from http://kuttler.eu/post/wordpress-style-version-conditional-comments/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you already solved the problem. You may also check the following code for another solution:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wps_add_ie_html5_shim' );
/**
 *  Add IE conditional html5 shim to header
 */
function wps_add_ie_html5_shim() {
    global $is_IE;
    if ( $is_IE ) {
        echo '<!--[if lt IE 9]>';
        echo '<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>';
        echo '<![endif]-->';
    }
}
```

You may also check specific browser using wordpress global variables like bellow:

Browser Detection Booleans
These globals store data about which browser the user is on.

```
$is_IE (boolean) Internet Explorer
$is_iphone (boolean) iPhone Safari
$is_chrome (boolean) Google Chrome
$is_safari (boolean) Safari
$is_NS4 (boolean) Netscape 4
$is_opera (boolean) Opera
$is_macIE (boolean) Mac Internet Explorer
$is_winIE (boolean) Windows Internet Explorer
$is_gecko (boolean) FireFox
$is_lynx (boolean)
```

For more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables

Answer (score 0):

I've done it in my header.php file in the past with no ill effects.

Comment: how can you do when you are writing a plugin?
i actually wanted to do with using function. because the theme will have on of function :)